# Add elements to a deeply nested list

Tags: r

I am trying to populate a deeply nested list - a 4 level list like this :-

```
mylist <- vector(5, mode = "list")
for (i in 1:5)
    {for (j in 1:2)
        {for (k in 1:3)
            {for (m in 1:4)
                {mylist[[i]][[j]][[k]][[m]] <- m
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Obviously I am doing something wrong but don't know what. I have a list called 'mylist' - a vector of model 'list'

At the  highest level, this is a 5 item list as shown by 5 values of 'i'. Now each of these 5 items are list of 2 items as shown by value of 'j'. Again, each of these 2 items are list of 3 items as shown by value of 'k'. Finally, this item is a list of 4 items shown by value of 'm'.

The idea is to populate 'mylist' variable with a certain value - I have made that value equal to 'm' for simplicity but its going to be different value - in fact its going to be the output from a regression. But that doesn't matter - obviously, but what does is how to do it and I can't get it going.

It seems to work with values of all of the variables have a value of 1. It also works when 'i' = 1, 'j' = 1, 'k' = 1 and for all values of 'm' (that is 'm' going from 1:4. However, got the 'subscript out of bounds error' when 'j' goes beyond 1. Not sure if that would be the case with values of 'k' also being greater than 1 (in my real case, k went from 1:1) - so, couldn't test it.

Any suggestions, where am I going wrong?

Best regards

Deepak

Comment: maybe you need to initiate the items ie `l[[i]]<-vector(2, mode = "list")` and so on

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to initiate the items ie `l[[i]]<-vector(2, mode = "list")` and so on

```
mylist <- vector(5, mode = "list")
for (i in 1:5){
    mylist[[i]] <- vector(2, mode = "list")
    for (j in 1:2){   
        mylist[[i]][[j]] <- vector(2, mode = "list") 
        for (k in 1:3){   
            mylist[[i]][[j]][[k]] <- vector(3, mode = "list")
            for (m in 1:4){   
                mylist[[i]][[j]][[k]][[m]] <- m
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also the older code works with j=k=1 because variables by default are treated as one element vectors in R.

Comment: Abdessabour Mtk <- That worked OK. Now please educate me as to what is happening! Why do I need to initiate each of the list items before the next loop iteration begins? Am I missing something here? Couldn't we have done it at the very start where we initiated the list like the very first statement if we know beforehand the length of the vector :- 'mylist <- vector(5, mode = "list")'. Granted in my case, I don't but just for my understanding, why do we have to do it this way if we knew the required details beforehand. But greatly appreciated.

Comment: you can't do it at the top level because you'd need another loop, making your code redundant.